# Insert NSArray with diffrent types into sqlite database?

Tags: objective-c, database, sqlite, nsarray

Hey i got a Question regarding inserting data into an sqlite database. I want to create general class for inserting data into a sqlite database. so i wrote a method like this:

```
-(void)saveData:(char)sqlstmnt andValues:(NSArray *)Values {

       char *sql= &sqlstmnt;

       sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL);

}
```

Now my problem is the given Array "Values" could be send by different classes and the content of that array is diffrent every time this method is called. it contains int, bool, float, text. so is there a way or a method that could "scan" with type a part of an array got? 
something like:

```
if ([Values objectAtIndex:i isINT]) {
    sqlite3_bind_int(statement, i, [Values objectAtIndex:i]);
}

if ([Values objectAtIndex:i isFLOAT]) {
    sqlite3_bind_float(statement, i, [Values objectAtIndex:i]);
}

if ([Values objectAtIndex:i isAnBOOL]) {
    sqlite3_bind_bool(statement, i, [Values objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

it would be great if anybody could help me with that.

because i need the type of it

Comment: Why not use the [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) library? That contains already methods like `- (BOOL)executeUpdate:(NSString*)sql withArgumentsInArray:(NSArray *)arguments`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`isKindOfClass:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass%3a) and [`objCType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSValue/objCType)

```
id object = ...

if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    // object is a string
}
else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    if (strcmp([object objCType], @encode(BOOL)) == 0) {
        // bool
    }
    else if (strcmp([object objCType], @encode(int)) == 0) {
        // int
    }
    else if (strcmp([object objCType], @encode(float)) == 0) {
        // float
    }
    else if (strcmp([object objCType], @encode(double)) == 0) {
        // double
    }
    // and so on
}
```